# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, seleniumwire

I am trying to open a website with a rotating authication proxy and I get this error. I dont understand why this is happening, im very new to coding and been watching alot of videos lmfao, but please help <3

`````
  File "B:\test\testchrome.py", line 21, in <module>
    driver.get('https://www.expressvpn.com/what-is-my-ip')
  File "C:\Users\o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 449, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})
  File "C:\Users\o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
  (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.100)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        (No symbol) [0x011137D3]
        (No symbol) [0x010A8B81]
        (No symbol) [0x00FAB36D]
        (No symbol) [0x00FA772D]
        (No symbol) [0x00F9DC65]
        (No symbol) [0x00F9F033]
        (No symbol) [0x00F9DF02]
        (No symbol) [0x00F9D324]
        (No symbol) [0x00F9D241]
        (No symbol) [0x00F9BC95]
        (No symbol) [0x00F9C518]
        (No symbol) [0x00FACF4C]
        (No symbol) [0x01011E01]
        (No symbol) [0x00FFB41C]
        (No symbol) [0x01011215]
        (No symbol) [0x00FFB216]
        (No symbol) [0x00FD0D97]
        (No symbol) [0x00FD253D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0138ABF2+2510930]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013B8EC1+2700065]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013BC86C+2714828]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x011C3480+645344]
        (No symbol) [0x010B0FD2]
        (No symbol) [0x010B6C68]
        (No symbol) [0x010B6D4B]
        (No symbol) [0x010C0D6B]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x771000F9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E17BBE+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E17B8E+238]````
`````

Answer (score 1):

This error...

```
File "C:\Users\o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 449, in get
  self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})
```

implies there was a error with the `get()` request.

I executed a basic *Selenium-Python* code block accessing the url https://www.expressvpn.com/what-is-my-ip as follows:

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.expressvpn.com/what-is-my-ip')
  driver.save_screenshot("what-is-my-ip.png")
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: what-is-my-ip]

---

### Conclusion

The basic program accessing the url *`https://www.expressvpn.com/what-is-my-ip`* works absolutely fine. So there can be two reasons for the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

Either the *Proxy* is down/invalid or the *Proxy* settings are incorrect.

---

### References

Links to couple of useful documentations:

- [How to Fix ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED in Google Chrome](https://aboutssl.org/how-to-fix-err-tunnel-connection-failed-in-chrome/)
- [How to Fix “err_tunnel_connection_failed” in Google Chrome](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/google-softwaretips/how-to-fix-err_tunnel_connection_failed-in-google-chrome/)
- [How To Fix ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED in Chrome](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/err_tunnel_connection_failed/)